# LRU Data eviction in Memcached

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am using AWS Memcached to load around 30 MB of data. All the keys are 9 bytes each and the values are 1 byte each.

```
 Key       Value
 001000335 N 
 001000336 Y
```

Since all the objects are of the same size, if a slab class's memory expires, will a higher slab class be used ? or will LRU data be evicted from the current slab?

I am new to both AWS and Memcached. Appreciate any help on this.